# Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. Please update the following components: Control(s)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, warnings

I'm receiving this type of warning but I don't understand why:

```
react-dom.development.js:67 Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

* Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
* If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at: https://reactjs.org/link/derived-state
* Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 18.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: Control(s)
printWarning    @   react-dom.development.js:67
warn    @   react-dom.development.js:34
./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactStrictModeWarnings.flushPendingUnsafeLifecycleWarnings   @   react-dom.development.js:11530
flushRenderPhaseStrictModeWarningsInDEV @   react-dom.development.js:23822
commitRootImpl  @   react-dom.development.js:23005
unstable_runWithPriority    @   scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11276
commitRoot  @   react-dom.development.js:22990
performSyncWorkOnRoot   @   react-dom.development.js:22329
scheduleUpdateOnFiber   @   react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer @   react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates    @   react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer    @   react-dom.development.js:26020
render  @   react-dom.development.js:26103
./src/index.js  @   index.js:11
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap 74ac790…:678
fn  @   bootstrap 74ac790…:88
0   @   socket.js:24
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap 74ac790…:678
(anonymous) @   bootstrap 74ac790…:724
(anonymous)
```

I don't know what it is the Control(s) component, but I see that it start by the render in ./src/index.js. But the code in ./src/index.js is:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT;

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Am I using old library to get this error? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: You are most likely getting this from using a library or dependency that hasn't been updated in quite some time. You can either see if there is an update for it, or clone the package, and make the fix yourself.